# Is there any benefit of using GLS when the regressors are identical

Tags: time-series, least-squares, vector-autoregression, generalized-least-squares, seemingly-unrelated-regressions

I am reading Greene, Econometric Analysis, 7th Addition,

I am seeking a point of clarrification.

"The case of identical regressors is quite common [think a VAR mode].... In this special case, **generalized least squares** *is equivalent* to equation by equation **ordinary least sqaures**".

Can somebody explain why?

Is this because the covaraince matrix is the same when I estimate the first equation of a VAR versus the second equation? Or any other reasons?

Comment: Thanks @Cowboy Trader, so you're confimring, from the slides, .... "But, no gains if identical regressors –for example, in the CAPM.
 GLS is the same as OLS. " period, no exceptions.

Comment: Many econometrics textbooks, e.g. Davidson & McKinnon ["Econometric Theory and Methods"](http://qed.econ.queensu.ca/ETM/), p. 500, include proofs showing how the GLS estimator simply collapses to the equation-by-equation OLS estimator in the case you are interested in.

Comment: I think your title might be improved by asking "why" or "how" instead of "whether", otherwise it does not seem to match closely to your post.